# How to get fingerprint of a user from android fingerprint sensor and store it in database?

Tags: android

I am developing an application in which I want to use fingerprint for  authentication. I don't know how to read the fingerprint and store it in my own database. I used Fingerprintmanager class but don't have a clue how to read the fingerprint to get enrolled or register the user in my database.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android fingerprint API for time attendance app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33468694/android-fingerprint-api-for-time-attendance-app)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it doable to collect user fingerprint with android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39556723/is-it-doable-to-collect-user-fingerprint-with-android)

Comment: This question was asked one year ago.the duplicate question you are suggesting was asked three months back,@Michael