# Android fingerprint API for time attendance app

Tags: android, fingerprint, biometrics

I would like to build an app which allows employees to scan fingerprint with the support of Android app. Right now most fingerprint API (Touch ID or Android Imprint) only allows login to app. Is there any 3rd party API that allows usage of API to collect fingerprint and attach to my employee record, and verify when they scan finger? Thanks.

Answer (score 13):

No. In fact, the [Android Compatibility Definition for Android 6.0](https://static.googleusercontent.com/media/source.android.com/en//compatibility/android-cdd.pdf) states in the Fingerprint section (7.3.10):

> MUST NOT enable 3rd-party applications to distinguish between individual fingerprints.

Therefore while you could write an app that uses fingerprint as a mechanism to authenticate the user, any registered fingerprint associated with the current user account could be used.

This would mean that if you want to differentiate each employee, they would need their own user account or device, rather than having a single instance of the app that works for multiple users.

Comment: Thanks for the info.

Comment: Is there any improvements regarding this topic now? I have the same scenario.

Comment: The link is broken...Another one for Android 9 [https://source.android.com/compatibility/android-cdd.html#7_3_sensors](https://source.android.com/compatibility/android-cdd.html#7_3_sensors)
Stil the same recommandation :

Answer (score 5):

You're right, Android M or Samsung or iPhone APIs only allow to verify current user against user of device.

With Android M or Samsung or iPhone APIs you can't get fingerprint template or image.

As @ianhanniballake the only solution is to create a user in Android for each employee. But each employee need to select is user and after, he could be authenticated.

There's some fingerprint scanners compatible with Android Platform and with SDK for Android. These SDKs allow to get fingerprint image or template. Scanners are plugged on USB port so you can't charge tablet and use fingerprint scanner simultaneous. For instance:

- http://www.dermalog.com/en/products_solutions/fingerprintscanner/
- http://www.futronic-tech.com/product_fs80h.html
- http://www.crossmatch.com/authentication-hardware/

There's also some devices with integrated fingerprint scanner and with SDK to get fingerprint image or template.

To match fingerprint, some SDK have matcher but if you have lot of user you should use an [AFIS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automated_fingerprint_identification) solution.