# Callback/broadcast for Adding/Removing fingerprint from android device

Tags: android, security, keystore, fingerprint

Is there any callback or broadcast send when you are adding/removing a fingerprint from the device.

Is there a way to find the ID of the fingerprints if there are multiple fingerprints.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there's no callback for this. You have to check if some fingerprints are enrolled each time, as this:

```
FingerprintManager fingerprintManager = (FingerprintManager) context.getSystemService(Context.FINGERPRINT_SERVICE);
if (!fingerprintManager.isHardwareDetected()) {
    // Device doesn't support fingerprint authentication     
} else if (!fingerprintManager.hasEnrolledFingerprints()) {
    // User hasn't enrolled any fingerprints to authenticate with 
} else {
    // Everything is ready for fingerprint authentication 
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I'm interested in knowing if there is any way to find out if a new fingerprint was added to the device. I mean we can add up to 5 fingerprints , Is there a  way to get the Id of the fingerprint.?

Comment: Is there a way to get the Id of the fingerprint.?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33468694/android-fingerprint-api-for-time-attendance-app/33473549#33473549