# Can i get fingerprint data on display touch in android?

Tags: android

I am working on application where i need fingerprint data ( image ) and save it on the server. Can anybody tell me it is possible or not ?? Is there any way we get fingerprint.

Any comments would be appreciated.

Comment: This would only be possible if your device has some fingerprint hardware built-in. If you only want an image of a fingerprint, you can take an image from the front camera of the device.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33468694/android-fingerprint-api-for-time-attendance-app

Comment: But image from front camera doesn't  give you suitable fingerprint. Is there any other method of doing so ??

Answer (score 1):

As per the link below you can not take the finger print data but can authenticate from android system

[How to get Fingerprint input from user and save to sqlite in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38160643/how-to-get-fingerprint-input-from-user-and-save-to-sqlite-in-android)