# Get fingerprint templates from fingerprint scanner

Tags: android, fingerprint, biometrics

I want to build an biometric attendance android application. I want to get the fingerprints of each user and store them and match them accordingly. But i don't want to use the internet for storing the templates i want to store it in sqllite is it possible. If possible can u tell me the code to get fingerprint from a scanner

Comment: Welcome on Stack Overflow. Please read the [introduction tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to provide good example guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot save a fingerprint image or template. It is stated by Android in the [Fingerprint Section](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0.html).

The Fingerprint data is stored by android system in the phone at a secure location which is not accessible. You can write an app that gets and stores fingerprint to authenticate the user. You can go through this sample that demonstrates to use registered fingerprints to authenticate the user in your app.

https://github.com/googlesamples/android-FingerprintDialog

If you need fingerprint authentication for about 300 users, your best bet would be implementing an [AFIS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automated_fingerprint_identification) solutions. You can also check out this [github repo](https://github.com/lethalskillzz/Android-Fingerprint-Attendance-Client), but I cannot guarantee it's veracity.

Stating this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33473549/7461132), there's some fingerprint scanners compatible with Android Platform and with SDK for Android. These SDKs allow to get fingerprint image or template. Scanners are plugged on USB port so you can't charge tablet and use fingerprint scanner simultaneous. For instance:

http://www.dermalog.com/en/products_solutions/fingerprintscanner/

http://www.futronic-tech.com/product_fs80h.html

http://www.crossmatch.com/authentication-hardware/

There's also some devices with integrated fingerprint scanner and with SDK to get fingerprint image or template. But this would be out of scope for programming.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. But that limits the user to store up to 5 fingerprints only. I want a minimum of 300 fingerprints to be stored. And authenticate them

Comment: And how about a usb enabled fingerprint scanner? Like morpho etc

Comment: Please check the edited answer.

Comment: Thnk you so much sir that helped a lot