# How to search by fingerprint in Android

Tags: java, android, fingerprint, android-fingerprint-api

I want to create an Android app that search by fingerprint for users.

Every user will have account, I want store the fingerprint of every user in database and when I read any fingerprint I will search in my database for user how has this fingerprint.

How I can do it using Android? Would Google Fingerprint API help me?

Comment: Android 6.0 APIs and later has a Fingerprint Authentication API  https://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0. May be helpful: [USING ANDROID FINGERPRINT API FOR USER LOGIN AND REGISTRATION](https://inducesmile.com/android/using-android-fingerprint-api-for-user-login-and-registration/), and [Is it doable to collect user fingerprint with android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39556723/is-it-doable-to-collect-user-fingerprint-with-android)

Comment: You could use an external fingerprint scanner to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot store fingerprint on database. Exactly you can't even get the fingerprint object, it's not possible. How fingerprint works on Android is to authenticate to the device (Android system).

Maybe you are asking why google doesn't provide the info about each user's fingerprint. It is because of security, if people can get the fingerprint object, people can crack the android system and hack into people's phone.